# Storing data of form in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to find out about how to store the data of my form in Google app engine. I have made the form in html. What should I do now to store all the data entered in form?

An example or code would be nice to understand.

Comment: Which language do you use? Have you read any documentation on App Engine datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my two suggestions:

1. You are going to have to send the form data to your GAE server via an AJAX call ([jQuery link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). When your server (ie, Java servlet) receives the HTTP request, you can then perform whatever logic is required and then store the data into a datastore. I highly recommend that you give [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) a try. It is useful for GAE developers of all skill levels because of its ability to directly persist Java objects without using convoluted queries (ie, SQL).
2. Instead of directly submitting your HTML form to the server, I suggest that you convert the form into a JSON string on the client side and send that over instead. JSON is becoming the de-facto Internet data transmission format.

Comment: The author is using Python.

Comment: Even if he used Python, I gave him some language-agnostic techniques, such as the fact that he should be using an AJAX call to send an HTTP request to the server, store data into a datastore and send data as JSON instead as the default form format.

Comment: Why the downvote? I gave the author a Java example before he told me he was using Python. I only had helpful information in this post!